# $\sin(n+1)<\sin(n+2)<...<\sin(n+k)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem statement is as follows:
Determine the largest positive integer $k$ for which there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $$\sin(n+1)<\sin(n+2)<\sin(n+3)<\ldots<\sin(n+k)$$

I change the problem statement slightly to finding an $n$ such that $$\sin(n)<\sin(n+1)<\sin(n+2)<\ldots<\sin(n+k-1)$$

The first observation I made is that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is an increasing function in the interval $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}, 2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
Since, we can choose any arbitrarily large $n$, I choose my n such that $|\sin(n)-(-1)|$ is as small as possible, with $n$ being in the $4^{th}$ quadrant. (This is the part of my argument that I feel is the least sound) After this, we can increase the argument of the sine by $1$ up to $3$ times, from the $4^{th}$ quadrant, to the the $1^{st}$ quadrant before it spills over into the $2^{nd}$ quadrant, giving me the maximum value of $k$ to be 4.

Is this the right approach? I feel that maybe we can get a solution with $k=5$ by starting out $n$ in the $3^{rd}$ quadrant, maybe a value equivalent to $2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac1{2}+\epsilon$ such that $\sin(n+1)>\sin(n)$ (I don't see a way though, since $\pi+\frac1{2}<4$. Maybe the argument can also spill into the $2^{nd}$ quadrant somehow.)
Please help

Comment: If you already know that $5$ is the answer, you should look for an integer approximating $2\pi m$ and use it as the angle of the center element. Well known approximations of $\pi$ like $\frac{22}{7}$ might be helpful...

Comment: hmm, n=88 seems to work for k=5.. but how would I prove/find this solution manually? and, more importantly, how do I rigorously prove that k=6 is not possible then? @zwim

Comment: my statement was false, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=5$, we are trying to get $n+2$ as close to a multiple of $2\pi$ as possible to have a trade-off between the range of angles for $n$ and $n+1$ with negative sines and $\sin(n)<\sin(n+1)$ and the range of angles for $n+3$ and $n+4$ with positive sines and $\sin(n+3)<\sin(n+4)$. Using $\pi\approx\frac{22}{7}$, we get $44\approx 7\cdot 2\pi.$ Now we must check
$$
\sin(42) < \sin(43) < \sin(44) < \sin(45) < \sin(46)
$$
In general, we have
$$
\sin\alpha - \sin\beta = 2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sin 43-\sin 42 = 2\cos \frac{85}{2} \sin\frac{1}{2} > 0 \\
\sin 44-\sin 43 = 2\cos \frac{87}{2} \sin\frac{1}{2} > 0 \\
\sin 45-\sin 44 = 2\cos \frac{89}{2} \sin\frac{1}{2} > 0 \\
\sin 46-\sin 45 = 2\cos \frac{91}{2} \sin\frac{1}{2} > 0
$$
because $\frac{85}{2},\;\frac{87}{2},\;\frac{89}{2},\;\frac{91}{2}$ are all in the interval $\left(14\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}\, , \, 14\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which makes their cosines positive.

Now assume there was a solution with $k=6.$ Similar to the argument above, this would imply that there was an $n$ with
$\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right),$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right),$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right),$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{7}{2}\right),$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{9}{2}\right)$ all being positive at the same time. However, it can easily be seen that
$\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) > 0,$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right) > 0,$
$\cos\left(n+\frac{9}{2}\right) > 0$
cannot hold at the same time.

This can be shown as follows:

The intervals, in which the cosine function is positive, that is $\left(2m\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\, , 2m\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\;,\;m\in\mathbb{Z},$ have the distance $\pi$ from each other. That means, $n+\frac{1}{2}$ and $n+\frac{5}{2}$ must be in the same of those intervals (because $\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{2}< \pi$), and $n+\frac{5}{2}$ and $n+\frac{9}{2}$ must also be in the same of those intervals for the same reason. This means that $n+\frac{1}{2}$ and $n+\frac{9}{2}$ must be in the same of those intervals (because they are both in the same of those intervals as $n+\frac{5}{2}$). But this is impossible, because the intervals have length $\pi$ and $\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2} > \pi.$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch to show that $k\ge6$ is impossible:

Your argument sequence cannot contain 2 numbers that lie both in the same interval where $\sin(x)$ is falling $[2l\pi + \frac{\pi}2,2l\pi + \frac{3\pi}2]$. That applies both to the start and the end.

Considering that your value sequence needs to be increasing from first to second element, you know (from your last paragraph) that the first argument can start only after $2l\pi + \frac{3\pi}2 - \frac12$.

Doing the same argumentation at the end of the sequence, the last argument of the sequence must come before $2(l+1)\pi + \frac{\pi}2 + \frac12 = 2l\pi + \frac{5\pi}2 + \frac12$.

So all your $k$ arguments must lie in the interval $(2l\pi + \frac{3\pi}2 - \frac12, 2l\pi + \frac{5\pi}2 + \frac12)$, which has length $\pi+1 < 5$. You cannot have more than 5 integers in an interval of that length!

Knowing that $k=5$ 'works' is, as you realized, knowing that $2l\pi + \frac{3\pi}2 - \frac12$ is equally distributed $\mod 1$, so gets into the interval for example $[m-0.1, m]$ for some integer $m$, which is enough to guarantee $5$ arguments $m, \ldots, m+4$, as the upper bound $m - 0.1 + \pi + 1 > m+4$ (as $\pi > 3.1$).